# Selecting a column vector from a matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing

I would like to index a column vector in a matrix in Python/numpy and have it returned as a column vector and not a 1D array.

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
x[:,1]
>array([2, 4])
```

Giving

`np.transpose(x[:,1])`

is not a solution. Following the `numpy.transpose` documentation, this will return a row vector (1-D array).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Few options -

```
x[:,[1]]
x[:,None,1]
x[:,1,None]
x[:,1][:,None]
x[:,1].reshape(-1,1)
x[None,:,1].T
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does `x[:,[1]]` work while `x[:,1]` does not?

Comment: @tomka Well with the `[1]` indexing, basically we are passing a list of indices that just happen to contain just one element, so it keeps the dimensionality as is. With `1` as the index, which is a scalar, the dimensionality would be reduced along that axis of indexing and the no. of dims of the slice would be one less. I found one helpful link on this : https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Indexing